# Fastest way to get the min index of 1D array value in another 1D bin array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I want to get the index of one 1D array called `value` in another 1D array called `bin` and calculate the minimum index in each bin.

Here's the whole step:
[image: steps]

Here's my current method:

```
import numpy as np

bin = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
value = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 3.1])
extend_bin = np.append(bin[1:], np.iinfo('int').max)
mask = (bin[:, None] <= value[None, :]) & (value[None, :] < extend_bin[:, None])
res = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)[:-1]
```

However, when the two 1D arrays are longer, I could get the memory error because of the large 2D mask array:

```
import random
import numpy as np

length = int(4e6)

a = np.random.rand(length)
order = np.argsort(a)
bin = a[order]
value = np.random.rand(length)
random.shuffle(value)
extend_bin = np.append(bin[1:], np.iinfo('int').max)
mask = (a[:, None] <= value[None, :]) & (value[None, :] < extend_bin[:, None])
res = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)[:-1]
```

Memory error:

```
    mask = (a[:, None] <= value[None, :]) & (value[None, :] < extend_bin[:, None])
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.6 TiB for an array with shape (4000000, 4000000) and data type bool
```

Is there any simpler and valid method to deal with problem?

Comment: What about using the Pandas cut or qcut? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Comment: @chatax Thanks! I tested `pd.cut(df['value'], bins=bin, right=False)` and `pd.cut(df['value'], bins=bin, right=False, labels=False)`. Just find that `labels=None` could much slow down the speed! Could you post your answer and compare the speed? I suppose that would be interesting for users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the `pd.cut` proposed in the comments, one could use `numpy.digitize`:

```
import numpy as np
bin = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
value = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 3.1])
extend_bin = np.append(bin[1:], np.iinfo('int').max)
binned_values = np.digitize(value, extend_bin)
# The above returns [0, 0, 1, 2]
_, res = np.unique(binned_values, return_index=True)
# res equals [0, 2, 3], i.e. the first index where each value happens
```

This also works in the extended case:

```
from time import time
length = int(4e6)
a = np.random.rand(length)
bin = np.concatenate([[0], np.sort(a), [1]])
value = np.random.rand(length)
tstart = time()
binned_values = np.digitize(value, bin)
print(time() - tstart)
# On my machine, the above takes about 4 seconds
tstart = time()
_, res = np.unique(binned_values, return_index=True)
print(time() - tstart)
# And this takes less than one second
```